# Проблема с шрифтом Open Sans

Tags: html, шрифты

Доброе утро.
Я делаю сайт, на нем есть заголовок с шрифтом Open Sans и c font-weight: 600[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это с другого сайта, текст с шрифтом Open Sans и с font-weight: 700[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, почему на другом сайте жирная насыщенность выглядит тоньше, чем у меня полужирная.

Comment: Вероятно, вы на своём сайте забыли подключить полужирный Open Sans и у вас отображается жирный, а другой сайт наоборот забыл подключить жирный Open Sans и отображается полужирный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, это произошло из-за того, что на у Вас или на другом ресурсе не все подключены варианты жирности. И при отсутствии нужной жирности браузер берет близко подходящий по жирности вариант. Проверьте все ли у Вас выбрано или добавьте в вопрос код, как вы его подключаете